# Нужно ли прибегать к методу сплит для сортировки массива объектов?

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка, split

Нужно отсортировать  продукты с тремя полями (инт и два стринга) по методу `quicksort`. Не знаю правильный алгоритм. Нужно ли использовать метод сплит, а затем разделенную строчку прогонять через `quicksort`?

```java
Product[] products = {
        new Product(24, "Bread", "Soft and tasty"),
        new Product(15, "Bubble gum", "Makes u love it!"),
        new Product(95, "Chips", "So crispy, so yummy!")};
```

Comment: А к чему вы собираетесь применить split? )

Comment: уже понял, что абсолютно ни к чему.Но алгоритм qSort не могу интегрировать, точнее, построить должным образом

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сортировать ArrayList<DataModel>?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195527/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-arraylistdatamodel)

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно реализовать интерфейс Comparator Java. Можно почитать [тут](https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/interfejsy-comparable-comparator-java/)

Answer (score 1):

Для сортировки массивов можно использовать метод [`Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)), передав туда цепочку компараторов - по каким полям, в каком порядке и в каком направлении сравнивать:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Product[] products = {
            new Product(24, "Bread", "Soft and tasty"),
            new Product(24, "Bread", "Taste and softy"),
            new Product(15, "Gumble bug", "Makes u love it!"),
            new Product(15, "Gummle bum", "Makes u love it!"),
            new Product(15, "Bubble gum", "Makes u love it!"),
            new Product(95, "Chips", "So crispy!"),
            new Product(95, "Chips", "So yummy!"),
            new Product(95, "Chips", "So crispy, so yummy!")};

    Arrays.sort(products, Comparator
            .comparing(Product::getField1, Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .thenComparing(Product::getField2)
            .thenComparing(Product::getField3));

    Arrays.stream(products).map(Product::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    // {95, Chips, So crispy!}
    // {95, Chips, So crispy, so yummy!}
    // {95, Chips, So yummy!}
    // {24, Bread, Soft and tasty}
    // {24, Bread, Taste and softy}
    // {15, Bubble gum, Makes u love it!}
    // {15, Gumble bug, Makes u love it!}
    // {15, Gummle bum, Makes u love it!}
}
```

В классе `Product` должны присутствовать геттеры для соответствующих полей:

```java
public class Product {
    private final int field1;
    private final String field2;
    private final String field3;

    public Product(int field1, String field2, String field3) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    public int getField1() { return field1; }

    public String getField2() { return field2; }

    public String getField3() { return field3; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + field1 + ", " + field2 + ", " + field3 + '}';
    }
}
```